# Setting up Github post-receive webhook with private Jenkins and private repo

Tags: jenkins, github

I'm trying to set up a private GitHub project to send a post-receive request to a private Jenkins instance to trigger a project build on branch push. Using latest Jenkins with the GitHub plugin.

I believe I set up everything correctly on the Jenkins side because when sending a request from a public server with curl like this:

```
curl http://username:password@ipaddress:port/github-webhook/
```

results in:

```
Stacktrace: net.sf.json.JSONException: null object
```

which is fine because the JSON payload is missing. Sending the wrong username and password in the URI results in:

```
Exception: Failed to login as username
```

I interpret this as a correct Jenkins configuration. Both of these requests also result in entries in the Jenkins log. However, when pasting the exact same URI from above into the Github repository Post-Receive URLs Service Hook and clicking on *Test Hook*, absolutely nothing seems to happen on my server. Nothing in the Jenkins log and the GitHub Hook Log in the Jenkins project says *Polling has not run yet.*

I have run out of ideas and don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: Did you make sure that the Github server can access your Jenkins server and port?

Comment: How can I verify that? There are no restrictions on who can access my server over that port from the outside. Every random online server I tried to send a request from behaved as described in the question.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. Github doesn't seem to be sending the HTTP basic auth credentials along with the request.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Apache as a proxy in front of Jenkins. I Use NameVirtualHost...

```
<VirtualHost>
  --Snip---    

<Proxy *>
      AddDefaultCharSet Off
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
     --snip-- #You can tighten this to only allow from GITHUB ips.
</Proxy>

    RequestHeader unset Authorization
    RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic [AUTHSTRING]"
    ProxyPass / [AJP|HTTP]://[JENKINS]:[PORT]/
    ProxyPassReverse / [AJP|HTTP]://[JENKINS]:[PORT]/

</VirtualHost>
```

I run Jenkins in a tomcat container and use AJP, so the var [AJP|HTTP] can be either for the proxy. The [JENKINS] and [PORT] variables should be intuitive.

Now the hard part, [AUTHSTRING]!

Take the USERNAME:PASSWORD part and run it through this command:

```
$ echo -n 'username:password' | base64
 dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

(echo -n is important to remove the newline.) Take the result and put in [AUTHSTRING]

You should be able to remove the user:password from the line at github.